# How to break table row in column to fixed width

Tags: html, css

How can I break my table row in columns to make the table fit a fixed width just like is shown in the image attached?

[image]

I have tried work-break and border-collapse but wont give the result I want.

```
table {
word-break: break-all;
font-size: 12px;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for downvoting.. I just dont know how I should go about it. Anyway I posted what I have tried but I dont think it will help much

Comment: I didn't downvoted. I just need to see some code in order to give you some advices/ideas ;)

Answer (score 0):

Structure your table correctly :)

Example

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/55jK3/)

HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Friday</th>
            <th>Saturday</th>
            <th>Sunday</th>
            <th>Average</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>$100</td>
            <td>$100</td>
            <td>$100</td>
            <td rowspan="4">$100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Friday</th>
            <th>Saturday</th>
            <th>Sunday</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>$100</td>
            <td>$100</td>
            <td>$100</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: solid 1px #CCC;
}
th, td {
    border: solid 1px #CCC;
}
```